# C# byte array - writing in the middle

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the task of reading data from a source in chunks, and storing the entire result in a byte array. Specifically, I need to make subsequent calls to "Socket.Receive". I would like to allocate the byte array with the final size in advance, and each time give the position within the array to copy data into. This, to avoid an extra copy.
In C++, you simply give the offset of the array. Could not figure out how to give the Receive method a location in the middle of the byte array...

Can this be done in C#?

Comment: How hard did you [look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If you know the total length of data and want to store it all into a single array, then you can use `Array.Copy` which allows you to to copy the contents of one array to another with a given source offset and destination offset.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that *will work*, but it isn't necessary in this case

Comment: The you should use List<byte> instead of byte[].

Answer (score 0):

There are overloads to `Receive` that accept the offset and count to read. You can use them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive(v=vs.110).aspx - for a specific example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thanks!

Comment: @user4212919 tip: assuming you are using Visual Studio, when you press `.` (for `socket.Whatever`) you get the intellisense popup; if you have resolved a method name, you can press the up and down arrows to show all the available overloads. Basically, all of this information is **directly available** in the editor: http://i.stack.imgur.com/g72P2.png